# AWS S3 RSS Feed

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, rss, podcast

I just started podcasting, and made my first podcast. I recorded it and am using auphonic.com to level out the audio and add the intro and outro - once this is done, it pushes the mp3 output to AWS S3.  It sounds amazing, the bucket is open to the public, and it's accessible to listen to via the URL made available in the file.

I need to create an RSS feed (for iTunes and to import podcasts onto my WordPress website via PowerPress).  I spent too much time over the weekend researching this - I'm told that this can be done using AWS Lambda, but I can't seem to find any good examples of how this is done.

*Can anyone offer good resources on how to create an RSS feed with AWS Lambda, or have other suggestions?*

In the meantime, I've uploaded my podcast to `anchor.fm`, which creates the feed and I can import that way. Anchor.fm is "free", but it looks like I'm essentially giving away my content, which is okay for now as I get started- but long term I'd like to create my own RSS, as noted above.

Any help is much appreciated - browsing AWS forum had several people asking this question with no answers.

Answer (score 0):

Search engine results initially presenting links to podcasts by or about AWS, iTunes, etc. doesn't make finding any explicit answer(s) either.

Happily, I remembered enough from this Reddit [comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/7sj8dn/how_to_make_an_rss_feed_from_items_added_to_an_s3/). It may not be complete or direct enough to implement verbatim, but hopefully, it helps you a bit because it got me on the right track.

Comment: thanks, will take a look at this - appreciate the help!

Comment: @JasonMorris no problem! Please do remember to post here if you find and/or figure out more. Itd be much appreciated!